# concatenate the following defined strings 1,2, and 3 and place it into string 4

Tags: assembly, x86-16

```
 .MODEL SMALL

 .STACK 100H

 .DATA?
    STRING1  DB  "The Computer Programmers Motto:", 13,10
    STRING2  DB  "When in doubt,", 13,10
    STRING3  DB  "mumble!", 13,10
    STRING4  DB   128 dup(?)
    STRING5  DB   128 dup(?)

    lstring EQU $ - string1
    strlen EQU "9"

    .CODE

START:
    MOV AX, @DATA               ;   set up addressability of data
    MOV DS,AX                   ;
    MOV     SI,0                ;   index register
    MOV     CX,LSTRING          ;   loop counter number of bytes to move
L1:
    MOV     AL,STRING1[SI]      ;   get char from source
    MOV     STRING4[DI],AL      ;   store in the target
    INC     SI                  ;   move to next character
    LOOP    L1                  ;   repeat for entire string

    mov ax, 4000h               ;   set up service to display string
    mov bx, 1                   ;   to monitor
    mov cx, lstring             ;   number of bytes to print
    mov dx,OFFSET string1       ;   where to find it
    int 21h                     ;   do it

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

    MOV AX, @DATA               ;   set up addressability of data
    MOV DS,AX                   ;
    MOV     SI,0                ;   index register
    MOV     CX,LSTRING          ;   loop counter number of bytes to move
L2:
    MOV     AL,STRING1[SI]      ;   get char from source
    MOV     STRING4[DI],AL      ;   store in the target
    INC     SI                  ;   move to next character
    LOOP    L2                  ;   repeat for entire string

    mov ax, 4000h               ;   set up service to display string
    mov bx, 1                   ;   to monitor
    mov cx, lstring             ;   number of bytes to print
    mov dx,OFFSET string4       ;   where to find it
    int 21h                     ;   do it

    mov ah,4ch                  ;   set up service to return to OS
    int 21h

    END start
```

I have code to place the strings on separate lines but I cant get it to display the 4th line all in a row??? I am trying to create a loop to display all three of the first strings in the 4th string on 4 lines

```
The computer programmers motto
when in doubt
mumble
The computer programmers motto when in doubt mumble
```

Comment: Since your strings have embedded newlines, if you concatenate them you will still have line breaks. You need to remove them. PS: Next time please fix your formatting if you see that it's broken.

Comment: I understand that but I need the output to look like ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ So if I remove them (13,10) and add a 0 to the end it prints it on one line but then how do I get them to print the first 3 separate lines and then the 4th single line?

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem ... you remove the `13,10` while concatenating and only leave the last one.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm very new at this as you can probably tell. I need the output to do this                                                                                             The computer programmers motto
when in doubt
mumble
The computer programmers motto when in doubt mumble

Comment: I need it to like the little blue box above I can only get it to do either the first 3 lines or only the fourth line. I need it to do all four lines

Answer (score 1):

The initialization of *lstring* must not include *string4* and *string5*.

```
STRING1  DB  "The Computer Programmers Motto:", 13,10
STRING2  DB  "When in doubt,", 13,10
STRING3  DB  "mumble!", 13,10

lstring EQU $ - string1

STRING4  DB   128 dup(?)
STRING5  DB   128 dup(?)
```

You need to clear DI register.

```
MOV     SI,0                ;   index register
MOV     DI,0
MOV     CX,LSTRING          ;   loop counter number of bytes to move
```

Here's how you remove the 13 and 10 from the output. Remember to use a smaller count when printing the result.

```
L1:
MOV     AL,STRING1[SI]      ;   get char from source
CMP     AL,13
JE      L1_
CMP     AL,10
JE      L1_
MOV     STRING4[DI],AL      ;   store in the target
INC     DI
L1_:
INC     SI                  ;   move to next character
LOOP    L1    
; Here you can add 1 final carriage return and linefeed.
```